# Why don't const parameters need to be initialized when they're defined?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int add(const int a, const int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

Why is the code above correct? I think the const variables should be initialized when they are defined in the formal parameters list.

Comment: What do you mean by "initialized"? They are function parameters, they get their values from the caller

Comment: Also I have similar problem in the pass-by-reference method. I think we should initialize the &something in the formal parameter list.

Comment: You don't initialize function parameters in a function declaration. You can define default values for arguments, but that is completely unrelated to the argument being `const` or not. A function argument being `const` only means that it cannot be modified in the function body

Answer (score 4):

> I think the const variables should be initialized

They are certainly initialized. Every call to this function provides values for these parameters, which initializes them. Guaranteed. Every time. And it doesn't matter if they are `const`, or not. They'll still get initialized every time this function gets called. There are no other alternatives, that's simply how C++ works on a fundamental level.

> when they are defined in the formal parameters list.

This is, technically, not a definition. This is a declaration.

You will find that the same C++ keyword will often mean (sometimes slightly, sometimes radically) different things, depending on its context.

When the `const` keyword gets used to declare an object in global scope, the object must certainly be initialized, to something:

```
const int a;
```

If this is a global variable definition, then this is ill-formed, and it won't compile.

But function parameters are not global variables.

Comment: OK,thanks! Does it mean that only global const variables need to be initialized and local don't have to? And I am not quite sure about the difference of definition and declaration in your explanations......

Comment: No, all `const` objects must be initialized. As I explained in my first paragraph, these `const` objects ***are*** initialized.

Answer (score 2):

'const' here is a promise that the function will not modify those values. The values passed in do not have to be constants.

Answer (score 1):

### Lexical Environments

A **lexical environment** is a name ⟶ object lookup. That is to say, I can give something a name (and a type) and associate it with some object value.

```
int x = -7;           /*
↑   ↑    ↑
↑   ↑    object value
↑   name
type                  */

std::string s = "Hello world!";
//          ↑      ↑
//          ↑      object value
//          name
```

There are also times when the name ⟶ object association can be modified. With normal variables, we can assign a value either at the time of creation:

```
int x = -7;         // associated with a value at creation
```

or at some other time:

```
string name;        // associated with a default value
name = "Bon-Jovi";  // associated with a new value
```

In C and C++ we can tell the compiler that the name ⟶ object association cannot be changed when we use the keyword `const`:

```
const x = -7;
x = 42;             // compile error: cannot change x’s value
```

The degree to which the `const`ness of a value is permanent depends on various factors not discussed here, but the idea is simply that you are telling the compiler and, importantly, *users of your code* that you guarantee not to try to change things marked `const`.

<sup>Also, this is a vast simplification of how things work underneath, but it is how *the language* views the universe, and how *you, the programmer* generally should as well.</sup>

---

### Formal Argument Names •vs• Actual Argument Values

Now some more vocabulary. A **function** has ***formal argument names*** (or *formal parameter names*, but in C and C++ we use the word “argument” instead of parameter), which is to say, we are telling the compiler what *names* we want to use when a local lexical environment is created for the function.

When we **invoke** (or *call*) a function, we supply ***actual argument values***. These actual values are *duplicated* and the *duplicate values* are associated with the formal argument names in the function’s new, local lexical environment.

An example:

```
void f( int x )            // formal argument name == “x”
{
  std::cout << x << "\n";  // print the integer value associated with “x” in
}                          // f()’s current (local) lexical environment
```

Here we have defined code that behaves with a locally-associated (local to the function) lexical name — in this case, `x`.

We invoke the function later:

```
int airspeed_velocity_of_unladened_sparrow = 11 /* m/s */;
int number_thou_shalt_count_to = 3;

f( airspeed_velocity_of_unladened_sparrow );  // actual argument value = 11
f( number_thou_shalt_count_to );              // actual argument value = 3
f( -7 );                                      // actual argument value = -7
```

Each time the function is invoked, a new lexical environment is created for the function, with the formal argument names associated with duplicates of the actual argument values.

Once the function finishes its business, its local lexical environment is destroyed and program control returns to where the function was invoked.

This idea of associating (or **binding**) values to names is exactly what a lexical environment is about, and how functions work. It would be really, really pointless if I couldn’t re-use `f()` with different values of its `x` each time I invoke it.

---

### Call by Value •vs• Call by Reference

So far we have described *call-by-value* semantics: a local copy of an object’s value is created and bound to a local name.

In C++, however, it is possible to create a *reference*. A **reference** is an alias for another, extant object value. In other words, we can have multiple names in our lexical environment referring to the same object value!

```
int   x = 12;  // x ⟶ integer 12
int & y = x;   // y ⟶ that ↑ same integer
y = 93;        // same as: x = 93
```

Or, to say it in yet another way, the integer object value `12` is now associated with *two* names (`x` and `y`), either of which can be used to access the integer object.

A reference argument does the same thing, except the function’s local lexical environment is created with an alias name for a value in the caller’s lexical environment!

```
void f( int & x )
{
  x += 1;  // `x` is an alias for... what?
}

int num_birds_in_hand = 0;
f( num_birds_in_hand );  // f()-local `x` == `num_birds_in_hand`
std::cout << x << "\n";  // prints 1!
```

In other words, when we bind (or associate) `f()`’s local `x` to an object, we simply bind it to the same object that `num_birds_in_hand` is bound to.

Or, to say it in yet another way, the integer object value `0` is now associated with *two* names (`num_birds_in_hand` and `x`), either of which can be used to access the integer object.

As long as the `f()`’s local lexical environment exists, the integer associated with the name `num_birds_in_hand` is also associated with the name `x`.

(And again, when the function terminates, its lexical environment is destroyed, and `num_birds_in_hand` no longer has any aliases.)

And, for the beauty of it all, each time we invoke `f()` we can initialize its local lexical environment with `x` aliasing a different object value.

```
int I_am_different = 37;
f( I_am_different );
std::cout << I_am_different << "\n";  // prints “38”
```

---

### Const References

This reference thing can cause a problem. Sometimes we want a some kind of promise that my `num_birds_in_hand` will ***not*** be modified, even if I give out an alias to it.

This is what a `const` formal argument is for. By marking the formal argument with `const`, we promise that when the function is invoked and a local lexical environment is created, it will not be used to change the actual argument value.

```
void g( const int & x )  // const == promise not to modify x’s object value
{
  x += 1;                // compile error: cannot change x’s value
}
```

The purpose of a reference argument is twofold: allow a function to modify a value in the caller’s lexical environment, and avoid having to make a copy of something expensive (or non-copyable). For example, `fstream` objects in the Standard Library cannot be copied. Hence we can only pass them as references. You see this with insertion operator overloads:

```
std::ostream & operator << ( std::ostream & outs, const my_type & value )
{
  // serialize whatever my_type object may be (possibly something large
  // or non-copyable) and output it to the `outs` stream.
  // Once done, we return the argument stream:
  return outs;
}

my_type quux;
std::cout << quux << "\n";
```

---

### Const Values

In the case of the code you showed us:

```
int add( const int a, const int b )
```

there really isn’t much point in marking `a` and `b` as `const` — no one cares what `add()` does with its local *copies* of the actual argument values.

(Sometimes the person writing the function’s code cares, so he or she will mark the formal argument name with `const`. But no one *using* the function cares.)

(That said, sometimes people actually do care. In the example code it does tell the caller that `a` and `b` won’t have something weird done to them before using their values. But I would argue that that just means that the caller knows too much about the function’s internal workings. As far as I should know, when *invoking* a function, *how* the function does its job should be unknown magic to me.)

Ultimately, however, it does not matter whether pass-by-value arguments are tagged `const` or not.

---

### tl;dr

Formal argument names are *initialized* with actual argument values *every time a function is invoked* — a new lexical environment, local to that function, is created, binding the formal argument names to actual argument values, before the function’s code is executed. (Once the function `return`s, its lexical environment is destroyed and program control is returned to the caller.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I still need some time to fully understand your explanation.

Comment: Yeah, it is a lot to take in. Don’t worry. Learning this stuff is hard. Keep going and this still will all seem very basic before too much longer.